# How can I use `unsafe` to create multiple references?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use unsafe to prevent the borrowchecker from blocking something safe. However, the unsafe block does not seem to have any effect.

Here's a sample code to reproduce the issue :

```rust
struct Element {
    pub data: usize,
}

unsafe fn recursiveFunction(element: &Element, elements: &mut Vec<Element>) {
    elements.push(Element {
        data: element.data + 1,
    });
    let index = elements.len() - 1;
    if elements.last().unwrap().data > 100 {
        return;
    }
    unsafe {
        recursiveFunction(&elements[index], elements);
    }
}
```

Here, I still get the error "cannot borrow `*elements` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable". I know that `element` will never point to invalid data.

Comment: What makes you think that recursive call is safe? "I know that element will never point to invalid data" how?

Comment: this isn't what `unsafe` does in rust. References still have to obey all their previous rules, but in `unsafe` blocks you are allowed to use (dereference) raw pointers, which don't have to obey such rules and call unsafe functions, like the ones in `UnsafeCell` which can violate *some* rules (it's allowed to mutate data through a shared reference). If you'd like to learn more about unsafe, the Rust book's chapter on it as well as the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/) are great sources of information!

Comment: `unsafe` does not disable the borrowchecker.

Comment: @JaredSmith Nowhere are elements deleted, only added.

Comment: @Inuit that doesn't guarantee they'll always be at the same address such that a borrowed reference to it is valid... this whole approach seems really...unidiomatic to say the least. Why not just cut with the grain of the language?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is creating a shared and an *exclusive* reference which overlap, that's not possible, references in Rust *have to* obey [llvms pointer aliasing rules](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#pointer-aliasing-rules) or you invoke [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html)

But your function is easily written in safe Rust, you can just pass the index instead of a reference:

```rust
fn recursive_function(idx: usize, elements: &mut Vec<Element>) {
    elements.push(Element {
        data: elements[idx].data + 1,
    });
    let index = elements.len() - 1;
    if elements.last().unwrap().data > 100 {
        return;
    }
    recursive_function(index, elements);
}
```

But the initial element you're calling this with now has to be inside the vector as well.
We can mitigate that by creating a small wrapper:

```rust
fn wrapper(element: &Element, elements: &mut Vec<Element>) {
    elements.push(Element {
        data: element.data + 1,
    });
    recursive_function(elements.len() - 1, elements)
}
```

which can be called like the original `recursiveFunction`.

Comment: Yeah, but the wrapper is exactly what I want to avoid. The real function is quite a lot bigger (and more features will be added to it) so I don't want to duplicate the logic. At the same time, I don't want to extract the logic into a separate function because this recursive call will happen A LOT, so another function adds to performance costs.

Comment: I'd probably just use the function with the first element in the vector in that case, seems a bit weird to discard the "-1st" element anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because you want to use the same variable in both parameters in the function call, this is fixed by creating a new instance of the `element` (or a clone in this case) to reference this element from the `elements` array don't be compromised

On the other hand, the `unsafe` block does not work as you think it does, the `unsafe` block is for doing unsafe things, that is, things over which Rust loses control in memory management (like when you have a mutable static ), as indicated in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html)

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Element {
    pub data: usize,
}

fn recursiveFunction(element: &Element, elements: &mut Vec<Element>) {
    elements.push(Element { data: element.data + 1 });
    let index = elements.len() - 1;
    if elements.last().unwrap().data > 100 {
        return;
    }
    let element = elements[index].clone();
    recursiveFunction(&element, elements);
}
```